# Reverse PTR Record With Heroku

Tags: django, email, heroku

I am currently working on a Heroku hosted Django server. I'm using `django.core.mail`'s `send_mail` function to send e-mails through a gmail account I have set up. However, there seems to be a large amount of these e-mails going to spam. Looking at some [articles](http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/), it seems that the first thing I need to do is set up a reverse PTR record.

I am a) not sure how to check to see if this is set up on my heroku server and b) not sure how to set it up if I do need to. Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Thanks!

PS: My domain name is hosted under Go Daddy, although I'd imagine this is not that relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I use the PointDNS Heorku add-on to setup configure DNS for my domain.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pointdns

Maybe this will be what you're looking for.